# What do you call the act of taking science and making it available to the broader public?

Tags: single-word-requests

In French we have a word, *vulgarisation*, which is the act of synthesizing complex knowledge into a form that a broad audience can understand. I know that the final product is called *popular science* in English, but I'm not sure how you call the process of taking "hard science" and making it popular science, and it seems that *vulgarization* isn't often used in a positive light.

Comment: I don't think there _is_ a single word for this in English. 'Dumbing down' is often heard, but this has negative connotations. 'Making science more accessible' is perhaps the most succinct way of putting it.

Comment: In English, we also have the word [*vulgarization*,](https://www.wordnik.com/words/vulgarization) which has as one of its meanings: n. the act of making something attractive to the general public. The word suffers, however, from its connection to the word *vulgar*, which has a primary meaning of *crudely indecent*.

Answer (score 2):

The term you are after is [*popularization*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/popularize), which Oxforddictionaries.com defines thus:

> Make (something technical, scientific, or academic) accessible or interesting to the general public by presenting it in a readily understandable form:

Comment: The problem I have with this word is that its other meaning (*cause (something) to become generally liked*) is way more...popular. The two meanings are sort of ambiguous without context (you couldn't use it in a headline, for instance) and the one I'm trying to convey can easily be shadowed.

Comment: @zneak You couldn't use it in a headline? That means PLOS ONE has done the impossible, and so did someone at the Brussels University... Context is everything, but based on the links I gave, it seems the expression is readily used and understood in the correct way?

Comment: @zneak I'd dispute your claim. In 'popularising the wazoo hairstyle', the 'make popular' sense is obviously going to be preferentially picked up on, but with 'popularising science', the frightening word science will skew 'popularising' towards the 'make accessible / less scary' sense.

Answer (score 1):

Not a single word, but certainly a single concept ***popularization of science***, scientists ***popularizing science***.
Examples of its usage:
[Scientists **Popularizing Science**: Characteristics and Impact of TED Talk Presenters](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0062403)
[Is **Popularization of Science** Possible?](https://www.bu.edu/wcp/Papers/Scie/ScieCorn.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think [diffusion of scientific knowledge](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:w2bS6akyotoJ:vertebrates.si.edu/fishes/ichthyology_history/ichs_colls/goode_g_brown.html%20diffusion%20of%20scientific%20knowledge%20museum&cd=14&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=it)  may  convey the idea of   contributing to the public understanding of science.

> For Goode, there was no distinction between pure and applied science; the increase of knowledge and the application of its benefits were inseparable. He was also a great believer *in the diffusion of scientific knowledge to the general public,* for which the museum was a primary vehicle.

Source: [Spencer Baird and Ichthyology at the Smithsonian](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:w2bS6akyotoJ:vertebrates.si.edu/fishes/ichthyology_history/ichs_colls/goode_g_brown.html%20diffusion%20of%20scientific%20knowledge%20museum&cd=14&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=it)